# Bottleneck on indexing performance with NumPy arrays (or creation of tuples)

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Imagine we have the following function:

```
def return_slice(self, k):
    return (self.A[self.C[k]:self.C[k+1]], self.B[self.C[k]:self.C[k+1]])
```

which is part of a class with arrays A, B and C which hold a ton of integers (upwards of 10^5). While calling this function a few times is fast enough, I've been noticing that ~2 million calls to this function are taking a very long time (my last few experiences have been showing ~12 seconds). I've managed to do a bit better with this:

```
def return_slice(self, k):
    pos = slice(self.C[k], self.C[k + 1])
    return (self.A[pos], self.B[pos])
```

which brings that down to ~6 seconds. This is still a bit unacceptable to me... I feel like I should change the whole way my arrays are structured, but I'm bringing this question to you because there may be something that I'm missing on why this is so slow.

Bear in mind that a "structure" to the values of k cannot be assumed, just assume that it is random for every execution.

I also think the creation of the tuple before returning may be the problem here, but it will take a ton of work to remove that -- I'd prefer to explore other alternatives.

Edit: A and B have the same size, but not the same data type.

Comment: Also, do you think using NumPy's structured arrays for A and B would help here, for this type of indexing? A and B have the same size.

Comment: Are A and B the same size?

Comment: @IgorRivin Yes, I should have included that in the post, ended up commenting instead

Comment: Have you tried avoiding the class, and profiling just a function like this `return_slice(k, A, B, C)`?

Comment: What do you want to do with this slices? Creating views on arrays is quite fast (as hpaulj) already showed, but normally doing something with the views is much slower...

Comment: I use a for loop on the elements of the result to modify other arrays based on the current element.

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
 self.D = np.vstack(self.A, self.B)

 def return_slice(self, k):
     pos = slice(self.C[k], self.C[k + 1])
     return tuple(self.D[:, pos])
```

Comment: A and B have the same size, but not the same dtype.

Comment: what are the dtypes?

Comment: 32-bit unsigned integers for A and 64-bit floating point for B

Answer (score 0):

Let's time some slicing variations:

```
In [447]: A = np.ones(10000)                                                                           
In [448]: timeit A[24:500]                                                                             

285 ns ± 0.807 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [449]:                                                                                              
In [449]: C = np.array([24, 500])                                                                      
In [450]: timeit A[C[0]:C[1]]                                                                          
632 ns ± 3.99 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [451]: def foo(k): 
     ...:     pos = slice(C[k],C[k+1]) 
     ...:     return A[pos] 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [452]: timeit foo(0)                                                                                
989 ns ± 4.33 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [453]: def foo(k): 
     ...:     pos = slice(C[k],C[k+1]) 
     ...:     return A[pos], A[pos] 
     ...:      
     ...:                                                                                              
In [454]: timeit foo(0)                                                                                
1.31 µs ± 30 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

So calling `foo` 2 million times will take more than 2 seconds.

Usually when I do timing test, a time under a microsecond looks good, unless it's a really trivial operation.  The key to speed in `numpy` is to reduce the number of calls, more so than speeding up individual ones. "vectorization" tries to eliminate many calls/iterations by using whole-array operations - one call using compiled numpy methods.  That can give 10x or better times.

`numba` can move us in the compiled direction.  With just as simple application:

```
In [456]: @numba.njit 
     ...: def foo(k): 
     ...:     pos = slice(C[k],C[k+1]) 
     ...:     return A[pos], A[pos] 

In [459]: timeit foo(0)                                                                                
555 ns ± 4.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

and collecting a million such calls:

```
In [473]: timeit [foo(0) for _ in range(1000000)]                                                      
1.09 s ± 38.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I believe you missed something important about my post: the loops that you do all call foo(0), while in my application there is no regularity to k. In consecutive iterations it may change from 0 to 4000, then to 1000, then to 10000, ...

Nonetheless I will try your suggestions, and see what I can get. I don't think reducing the number of calls is viable (think of this looping as breadth-first search calling a neighbours method of a graph class).